# Keycodes for javascript

Tags: javascript

This is list of key codes: https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Here keycode for "a" is `65` and for "b" is `66`

But  this simple test gives different result:

```
<textarea type="text" id="txt"></textarea>
```

js:

```
const input = document.querySelector('#txt');
input.addEventListener('keypress', event => {

    console.log( event.keyCode ) ;

});
```

keycode for "a" returns `97`, and "b" - `98`

What I misunderstood ?

Comment: Upper and Lower cases.  `A` is 65 and `a` is 97

Comment: I would seriously suggest looking for a much more recent, and less misleading, source for JavaScript information.

Comment: Consider using [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead so as not to have to map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lowercase "a" is 97, capital "A" is 65. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The keycode for `a` is **97** and for `A` is **65**. They are different for lowercase and uppercase letters. You can try it in the snippet.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#txt');
input.addEventListener('keypress', event => {

    console.log( event.keyCode ) ;

});
```

```html
<textarea type="text" id="txt"></textarea>
```